# Theme Development for WordPress Multisite Installation

Tags: theme-development, multisite, themes

I have built a lot of WordPress themes for individual clients. I am working on my first theme that will be used on a multisite installation. I want to make sure there isn't anything different I need to do knowing the theme will be used on a multisite install setup.

I did some Googling, but didn't find much. Can anyone share their tips, experience or articles that discuss the topic?

Comment: Tall order! I like this question but you need to post more in depth requirements other than "tips". This site is not really about broad subjects like this. Maybe describe what the users of the site will be handling and the distribution method you will use for assigning the sites.

Comment: ^ describe in your question btw. Do not comment to this in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes don't function differently on multisite. So you can develop a theme just the way you are used to. Depending on your coding habits, you might want to do more thorough testing if the theme has many options and customization possibilities.

The risks are inherent to multisite, not particularly to theming. One mistake will affect many sites. Updating your theme will require very thorough testing indeed, for risk of breaking lots of stuff. Options cannot easily be changed anymore.

So, much depends on your personality. If you are a disciplined coder, who thinks a theme through before he acts, you can go ahead as you're used to. If you're a trial and error kind of coder, you will need to toughen up.

Comment: "Themes don't function differently on multisite".... I guess it had a been a long while since you have seen a badly written theme.... but you can see from the questions here how people try to do ajax and generate CSS in a "non wordpress" way which you might get away with in a standalone install, but will break for sure in a multisite

Comment: .... in 4.7 there is the custom CSS option that IIRC is not available to multisite, so you might need to have your own functionality if this is something you want to give the user to play with....

Comment: @MarkKaplun Even well written themes may break on mulitisite, because with a dozen sites in operation there maybe a configuration you didn't think of. Might even be a silly css rule that doesn't play with all your columns options.

Comment: that is the difference between a theme tailored to a specific site and a theme for "general use". I agree it is also something to look for, and requires more testing but IMO this got nothing to do with multisite itself.